# Migrating away from Firebase to a SQL MBAAS on Android

Tags: android, firebase, mbaas

Firebase is great as a real-time database that elegantly stays synchronised across devices but the lack of data aggregation, counting and filtering (like "Group By", "Count", "Where" etc. in SQL) is proving to be a major roadblock to further development.

Is there a SQL-like MBAAS that people would recommend for someone without any I.T. knowledge? I can program in Java and know SQL but that's about it...

Thanks,
Riz

p.s. I also use Firebase as an authentication service for Facebook, Twitter, Email authentication so a feature like that would be great to.